# Azure function CRON Schedule expression

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

If I wish to run my function app at 11.15 PM to next day 1.15 AM(That mean MONDAY 11.15 PM start and TUESDAY 1.15 AM will end) and it will trigger every minute during this time.

Can anyone help me to write this CRON expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer triggers are designed for a single repeating interval. The only way to do this completely within a Function is to run the trigger once per minute, then abort if the current time isn't in the desired target time period.

Alternately, put your logic into an HTTP trigger configured to act as a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook), then use an Azure [scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-advanced-complexity) to configure start and stop times and intervals.

You won't be able to use the scheduler free plan since it can only run once per hour, but the standard plan can run once per minute. Scheduler pricing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-plans-billing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For an immediate implement your 1 st option will work I guess. Thank you for the details - McGuire

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this in three lines I think,

```
15-59 23 * * *
* 0 * * *
0-15 1 * * *
```

This will run it from 23:15-23:59 then 00:00-00:59 then 1:00-1:15

Comment: Hi DasDave, Thank you for your reply. Is it Like That :   --public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0/1 23 * * WED,SAT")]TimerInfo myTimer, TimerTrigger("0 0/1 0-1 * * THU,SUN")]TimerInfo myTimer1, TraceWriter log)   .. Can we pass multiple timer info like this? .. Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't pass multiple timer intervals to an Azure Function.